# MFC C++ CListBox get selected item

Tags: c++, mfc

First let me say that I've been searching for a solution for couple of days now...

I'm trying to get selected item for ListBox. This is my code:

```
CListBox * pList1 = (CListBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);
CString ItemSelected;
// Get the name of the item selected in the Sample Tables list box 
// and store it in the CString variable declared above 
pList1->GetText(pList1->GetCurSel(), ItemSelected);
MessageBox(ItemSelected, "TEST", MB_OK);
```

Now when i try this i get an error message saying "The Parameter is incorect"

Comment: `pList1->GetCurSel()` is not guaranteed to succeed (a listbox can have no selection at all). It returns `LB_ERR` in that case. That's not a valid index to pass to `CListBox::GetText`.

Comment: but there is a selection ... is there another way to do this ?

Comment: Try a full compile first. Then try to debug into it. Also, for testing, assign the `GetCurSel` value to a variable so you can confirm. Finally, any reason why you are not directly mapping the `CListBox` to a `CString` variable and just calling `UpdateData(TRUE)` and using the variable value?

Comment: Is your ClistBox Single selection or multiple selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks OK except error handling. Also `MessageBox` parameters look incorrect. The first parameter should be of type `HWND`. I believe that this is the root cause of your problems. Use MFC standard `AfxMessageBox` instead:

```
CListBox * pList1 = (CListBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);

int nSel = pList1->GetCurSel();
if (nSel != LB_ERR)
{
    CString ItemSelected; 
    pList1->GetText(nSel, ItemSelected);
    AfxMessageBox(ItemSelected);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, `MessageBox` needing `HWND` parameter. All the same, debugging the code should isolate his issue and on what line the error is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

If the CListBox is in single selection mode, the CListBox::GetCurSel will return the selected index.

If the CListBox is in multi-selection mode, you should use CListBox::GetSelItems which will return a list of indices.

You cannot mix'n'match the functions.

And always check return codes  (as others already wrote).

Answer (score 0):

If You already have a data member MyList(of classCListBox) :

```
int nSel = MyList.GetCurSel();
    CString ItemSelected;
    if (nSel != LB_ERR)
    {
        MyList.GetText(nSel, ItemSelected);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[**CWnd** class has a **MessageBox**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eebkf6f(v=vs.80).aspx) function which does not need a HWND parameter. But yes, **AfxMessageBox** is a little bit more easier to use and can be called anywhere in the MFC code without having a CWnd-derived object. And a beside note: if call a **WinAPI** function inside **MFC** code (not needed here, but possible in other cases) it's good to prepend it with scope resolution operator in order to avoid any confusion, mistake and/or name conflict (e.g. **::MessageBox**...).

One possible cause for "invalid parameter" error in OP code is that it uses an ANSI string literal ("TEST") in a UNICODE build configuration. This case, must use an UNICODE string literal (L"TEST") or a little bit better, use **_T** macro (_T("TEST")) that makes it possible to build in both ANSI and UNICODE configurations.